# Show custom message in WooCommerce checkout based on shipping country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, notice

I'm currently using the code below to show a custom message based on country:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'display_shipping_notice' );
function display_shipping_notice() {
    echo '<div class="shipping-notice woocommerce-info"  style="display:none">Please allow 5-10 business days for delivery after order processing.</div>';
}
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'show_shipping_notice_js' );
function show_shipping_notice_js(){
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            // Set the country code (That will display the message)
            var countryCode = 'GB';
  
            $('select#billing_country').change(function(){
                selectedCountry = $('select#billing_country').val();
                  
                if( selectedCountry == countryCode ){
                    $('.shipping-notice').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('.shipping-notice').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php 
}
```

The problem with this code is that it will only show the message if the country is changed or selected. However,  most customers already have their country pre-filled, so the custom message will not show.

I'm trying to find a way to alter the code to make the message always show when the correct country is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have revisited your code, changing:

- the **success** message (blue) to a **notice** message (green),
- the JQuery code to handle the country on load when DOM is loaded.

But note that your jQuery code is handling Billing country *(see at the end for shipping country)*.

Try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'display_shipping_notice' );
function display_shipping_notice() {
    echo '<div class="shipping-notice woocommerce-message" role="alert" style="display:none">Please allow 5-10 business days for delivery after order processing.</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'show_shipping_notice_js' );
function show_shipping_notice_js(){
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var countryCode  = 'GB', // Set the country code (That will display the message)
                countryField = 'select#billing_country'; // The Field selector to target
            
            function showHideShippingNotice( countryCode, countryField ){
                if( $(countryField).val() === countryCode ){
                    $('.shipping-notice').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('.shipping-notice').hide();
                }
            }

            // On Ready (after DOM is loaded)
            showHideShippingNotice( countryCode, countryField );

            // On billing country change (Live event)
            $('form.checkout').on('change', countryField, function() {
                showHideShippingNotice( countryCode, countryField );
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).
Tested and works.

[image]

---

**Caution:** If you want to handle **the shipping country** instead of billing country, replace:

```
                countryField = 'select#billing_country'; // The Field selector to target
```

with this:

```
                countryField = 'select#shipping_country'; // The Field selector to target
```

Now It will handle Shipping country.

Comment: Thanks!

I tried out the code and it works when I load the page with the required country. However, when I load the page with another country, and then select GB, It does not show.